# Meaning of $^2[\,1/2]$ terms in atomic spectroscopy

Tags: quantum-chemistry, spectroscopy, notation

I was trying to analyze some atomic emission spectroscopy data and I encountered unfamiliar notation of the terms for me.

Commonly, the electronic states of the atoms can be described by quantum numbers using the term notation ("L-S coupling"). The terms are given as:  $^{2S+1}L_{J}$, where $S$ is the total spin quantum number, $J$ is the total angular momentum quantum number and $L$ is the total orbital quantum number in spectroscopic notation.

However, in this table there are also terms having notations without letters ($S$,$P$,...), like $^{2}[\,1/2]^\mathrm{o}$ (black box). What does that mean and why are there separate cases for $J = 0$ and $J = 1$?

[**Edit**] The data has been taken from NIST Atomic Spectral Database for Ne I (neutral neon in spectroscopic notation).
[NIST database](https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/ASD/lines1.pl?spectra=Neon%20I&limits_type=0&low_w=&upp_w=&unit=1&submit=Retrieve%20Data&de=0&format=0&line_out=0&en_unit=0&output=0&bibrefs=1&page_size=15&show_obs_wl=1&show_calc_wl=1&unc_out=1&order_out=0&max_low_enrg=&show_av=2&max_upp_enrg=&tsb_value=0&min_str=&A_out=0&intens_out=on&max_str=&allowed_out=1&forbid_out=1&min_accur=&min_intens=&conf_out=on&term_out=on&enrg_out=on&J_out=on)
The notation, asked in this posted has already been explained here [Notation key by NIST](https://www.nist.gov/pml/atomic-spectroscopy-compendium-basic-ideas-notation-data-and-formulas/atomic-spectroscopy-2)

[image]

Comment: The notation of coupling schemes are explained here https://www.nist.gov/pml/atomic-spectroscopy-compendium-basic-ideas-notation-data-and-formulas/atomic-spectroscopy-2

Comment: I am not familiar with this type of coupling but it is called *LK* couping. The number in square brackets is *K*. It is always good to a give a reference when you paste an image.

Comment: I dont understand that notation. But my lecturer told me to study up L-S coupling so this kind of notation confused me.

Comment: But the transition looks like this? For example: I have a wavelength 352 nm so the transition is $^2[1/2]$ to $^2[1/2]^0$?

Comment: This notation is certainly not LS coupling. Ask your professor if he expects you to learn LK coupling.

Comment: It is probably, just not written with letter because L is not in the form of integer because the databese uses classic LS form for other elements so I guess the notation must remain the same

Comment: In addition to previous comments, you may find helpful to have a look at Herzberg's Atomic Spectra and Atomic Structure,

Comment: May also be helpful to read this original paper by Cowan and Andrew in 1965 "Coupling Considerations in Two-Electron Spectra" https://opg.optica.org/DirectPDFAccess/42879AAE-F5CE-452A-82787AE00DCEA0A0_52651/josa-55-5-502.pdf?da=1&id=52651&shib=578648&seq=0&mobile=yes